# await is only valid in async function fetch()?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже видел решение подобных проблем,но там были проблемы в написании своих функций,но не базовой.

Comment: О чем речь вообще?

Comment: Не могу отправить запрос на сервер,из-за данной ошибке

Comment: Так у вас же черным по белому написано, что await имеет место быть только внутри асинхронной функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
async function test() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

test().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  ~async function() {
    let response = await fetch(".").then(resp => resp.text())
    console.log(response)
  }()
</script>
```